# PYTHON How to generate 20 million unrepeatable random numbers

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

Need to generate 20 million unrepeatable random numbers with 8 characters length and save it in an array.
I try with multiprocessing,threading but it stays slow.

Try with multiprocessing:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import os,time
import numpy as np
rng = default_rng()
f=np.array([],dtype=np.int64)
def generate(q,start,stop):    
    numbers=[rng.choice(range(start,stop),replace=False) for _ in range(1000)]    
    q.put(numbers)       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timeInit = time.time()
    for x in range(20000):
        q=Queue()
        p = Process(target=generate,args=(q,11111111,99999999,))    
        p.start()        
        f=np.append(f,q.get())
        p.join()
    print(f)
    timeStop = time.time()
    print('[TIME EXECUTED] ' + str(timeStop-timeInit) +' segs')
```

Comment: What is an "unrepeatable" random number?  Do you mean that you need 20 million *unique* numbers?

Comment: Please finish your problem description.  What is "slow" in your terms?  If you're worried about speed, why are you encumbering your process with so much overhead?

Comment: Why do your numbers start at 11111111 instead of at 10000000?  Don't you want your results to include *all* possible 8-digit numbers?

Comment: @Prune 
That's right, obviously they can't be consecutive numbers..
I need something like [38214567,13821593, ......]

Comment: @Prune 
It's slow to the point that I can't see the output.
that's why I decided to use multiprocessing so as not to leave all the work to the main process

Comment: Hi @Fernando what is the purpose of those random numbers? What distribution are they drawn from?

Comment: @YangYushi They are for raffle tickets!

Comment: FYI: People are asking some of these questions because "random" means "unpredictable," and every constraint that you put on a random sequence makes that sequence just a little bit more predictable (i.e., a little bit less random.) In some applications, that's not a big deal, but in other applications (e.g., in cryptography) it can be a _very_ big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explained why you're doing all of that overhead.  I simply took a random sample from the candidate numbers:

```
from random import sample

result = sample(
    list(range(10**7, 10**8)),
    2*10**7
)
```

51 seconds on my laptop, with interference from other jobs.

---

I just ran a more controlled test on both solutions.  The one in this post took 48.5 seconds; the one from naicolas took 81.6 seconds, likely due to the extra list creation.

Answer (score 2):

This took less than 30 secs on my personal laptop, if it works for you:

```py
import random
candidates = list(range(10**7, 10**8)) # all numbers from 10000000 to 99999999
random.shuffle(candidates)
result = candidates[:20* 10**6] # take first 20 million
```

Comment: Corrected, my bad

Comment: Thx! 
It works but is still slow on my personal laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your idea. The random numbers that you are trying to generate are actually a bit tricky. Basically we are looking for a set of **unique** (non-repeatable) but random numbers. In this case, we can not draw random numbers from uniform distribution, because there is no guarantee that numbers are unique.

There are 2 possible algorithms. The first one is to generate A LOT of possible random numbers, and remove those repeated ones. For instance,

```py
import numpy as np


N = 20_000_000
L0 = 11_111_111  # legitimate int in Python
L1 = L0 * 9

not_enough_unique = True

while not_enough_unique:
    X = np.random.uniform(L0, L1, int(N * 2)).astype(int)
    X_unique = np.unique(X)  # remove repeated numbers
    not_enough_unique = len(X_unique) < N

random_numbers = X_unique[:N]
np.random.shuffle(random_numbers)
```

There is also another more "physics" approach. We can start with equal–spaced numbers, and move each number a little bit. The result will not be as random as the first one, but it is much faster and purely fun.

```py
import numpy as np

N = 20_000_000
L0 = 11_111_111  # legitimate int in Python
L1 = L0 * 9

lattice = np.linspace(L0, L1, N)  # all numbers have equal spacing
pertubation = np.random.normal(0, 0.4, N)  # every number move left/right a little bit
random_numbers = (lattice + pertubation).astype(int)

# check if the minimum distance between two successive numbers
# i.e. all numbers are unique
min_dist = np.abs(np.diff(random_numbers)).min()
print(f"generating random numbers with minimum separation of {min_dist}")
print("(if it is > 1 you are good)")

np.random.shuffle(random_numbers)
```

(Both algorithms generate the result within 10s on my laptop)